# Trying to avoid creating numerous variables in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have a lot of variables I will be using in this script. These variables are being used to grab data from each column in an uploaded file. I have added variables for each object type and I have about 12 more object types to add.  Isn't there a better way I can do this? I have the file it's grabbing data from here:

```
Action  Object  Solution ID hostgroup_name  alias
Add Host Group  ISD-CR  ISD-CR_database ISD-CR Database
Add Service ISD-CR  ISD-CR_database 
Update  Service Group   ISD-CR      ISD-CR Database
Delete  Service ISD-CR  ISD-CR_database
```

Here is the script I have so far.

```
from pynag import Model
from pynag.Parsers import config 
def addObject():

            # Add hostgroup object
            hg = Model.Hostgroup()

            hg.set_filename('/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(target_hostgroup_name))

            # Adding all attributes to allow any to be added if needed
            hg.hostgroup_name = target_hostgroup_name
            hg.alias = target_alias
            hg.members = target_members
            hg.hostgroup_members = target_hostgroup_members
            hg.notes = target_notes
            hg.notes_url = target_notes_url
            hg.action_url = target_action_url

            # Save
            hg.save()

            print "hostgroup added"

            # Add service object
            s = Model.Service()

            s.set_filename('/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(target_hostgroup_name))

            # Adding all attributes to allow any to be added if needed
            s.host_name = target_host_name
            s.hostgroup_name = target_hostgroup_name
            s.service_description = target_service_description
            s.display_name = target_display_name
            s.servicegroups = target_servicegroups
            s.is_volatile = target_is_volatile
            s.check_command = target_check_command
            s.initial_state = target_initial_state
            s.max_check_attempts = target_max_check_attempts
            s.check_interval = target_check_interval
            s.retry_interval = target_retry_interval
            s.active_checks_enabled = target_active_checks_enabled
            s.passive_checks_enabled = target_passive_checks_enabled
            s.check_period = target_check_period
            s.obsess_over_service = target_obsess_over_service
            s.check_freshness = target_check_freshness
            s.freshness_threshold = target_freshness_threshold
            s.event_handler = target_event_handler
            s.event_handler_enabled = target_event_handler_enabled
            s.low_flap_threshold = target_low_flap_threshold
            s.high_flap_threshold = target_high_flap_threshold
            s.flap_detection_enabled = target_flap_detection_enabled
            s.flap_detection_options = target_flap_detection_options
            s.process_perf_data = target_process_perf_data
            s.retain_status_information = target_retain_status_information
            s.retain_nonstatus_information = target_retain_nonstatus_information
            s.notification_interval = target_notification_interval
            s.first_notification_delay = target_first_notification_delay
            s.notification_period = target_notification_period 
            s.notification_options = target_notification_options
            s.notification_enabled = target_notifications_enabled
            s.contacts = target_contacts
            s.contact_groups = target_contact_groups
            s.stalking_options = target_stalking_options
            s.notes = target_notes
            s.notes_url = target_notes_url
            s.action_url = target_action_url
            s.icon_image = target_icon_image
            s.icon_image_alt = target_icon_image_alt

            # Save
            s.save()

            print "service added"

            # Add servicegroup object
            sg = Model.Servicegroup()

            sg.set_filename('/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(target_hostgroup_name))

            # Adding all attributes to allow any to be added if needed
            sg.servicegroup_name = target_servicegroup_name
            sg.alias = target_alias
            sg.members = target_members
            sg.servicegroup_members = target_servicegroup_members
            sg.notes = target_notes
            sg.notes_url = target_notes_url
            sg.action_url = '/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(target_hostgroup_name)

            # Save        
            sg.save()

            print "service group added"

try:
        current_file = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb"), delimiter='\t')
    except:  
        logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')
    else:
        for line in current_file:        
            for row in current_file:

                target_hostgroup_name = row[3]
                target_alias = row[4]
                target_members = row[5]
                target_hostgroup_members = row[6]
                target_notes = row[7]
                target_notes_url = row[8]
                target_action_url = row[9]
                target_host_name = row[10]
                target_service_description = row[11]
                target_display_name = row[12]
                target_servicegroups = row[13]
                target_is_volatile = row[14]
                target_check_command = row[15]
                target_initial_state = row[16]
                target_max_check_attempts = row[17]
                target_check_interval = row[18]
                target_retry_interval = row[19]
                target_active_checks_enabled = row[20]
                target_passive_checks_enabled = row[21]
                target_check_period = row[22]
                target_obsess_over_service = row[23]
                target_check_freshness = row[24]
                target_freshness_threshold = row[25]
                target_event_handler = row[26]
                target_event_handler_enabled = row[27]
                target_low_flap_threshold = row[28]
                target_high_flap_threshold = row[29]
                target_flap_detection_enabled = row[30]
                target_flap_detection_options = row[31]
                target_process_perf_data = row[32]
                target_retain_status_information = row[33]
                target_retain_nonstatus_information = row[34]
                target_notification_interval = row[35]
                target_first_notification_delay = row[36]
                target_notification_period = row[37]
                target_notification_options = row[38]
                target_notifications_enabled = row[39]
                target_contacts = row[40]
                target_contact_groups = row[41]
                target_stalking_options = row[42]
                target_icon_image = row[43]
                target_icon_image_alt = row[44]
                target_servicegroup_name = row[45]
                target_servicegroup_members = row[46]
```

Comment: what about using a dictionary for store your objects as value with particular key ? (e.g `{'var1':obj1,'var2':obj2,...}`)

Comment: Thanks, this is another option I'll take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in the same order every time, you could consider populating a list that you then could loop over, instead of doing it one by one.

For the "target" portion of your script, you could nest another loop `for range(3, 46)` as well, and pass the index to your list instead of manually for every number from 3 to 46.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. I just need to see if the order will be altered in any way or not.

Comment: If the ordering is different you could always use a dictionary and compare keys.

Comment: @bayernmunich, I also think your `else` statement after your `try` block is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this?

```
for line in current_file:
    for row in current_file:
```

If the first row is a header row and you're skipping it on purpose, you can use a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead.

It doesn't look like you'll be able to do much to clean this up, but you could factor out each "section" into its own function:

```
def save_hostgroup(name, alias, members, hostgroup_members, notes, notes_url, action_url):
    hg = Model.Hostgroup()
    hg.set_filename('/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(target_hostgroup_name))

    # Adding all attributes to allow any to be added if needed
    hg.hostgroup_name = target_hostgroup_name
    hg.alias = target_alias
    hg.members = target_members
    hg.hostgroup_members = target_hostgroup_members
    hg.notes = target_notes
    hg.notes_url = target_notes_url
    hg.action_url = target_action_url

    hg.save()
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I think putting each section into it's own function may be the best option, especially since I'm not trying to populate it with hard coded data.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes all the member names of an object are stored in a `dict`. You can access this `dict` with `vars(obj)` or `obj.__dict__`. You can then use the update method of the `dict` to add a set of names to your object.

eg.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return "SomeClass({})".format(
            ", ".join(
                "{}={!r}".format(key, value) 
                    for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
            )
        )
    __repr__ = __str__

target_names = ['var_a', 'var_b', 'var_c']
target_values = [1, 2, 3]

target = dict(zip(target_names, target_values))
assert target == {'var_a': 1, 'var_b': 2, 'var_c': 3}

s = SomeClass()
vars(s).update(target)

assert hasattr(s, 'var_a')
assert s.var_a == 1
print(s) # prints SomeClass(var_c=3, var_a=1, var_b=2)
```

Comment: I could create a class, this would help separate the values even if they are in the same column.

Comment: The class wasn't meant to be a suggestion on how to separate the data, just how you can populate the names on an object with a dict. However, separating your data into three separate dicts that hold the data that each different object type needs, is a good idea.